# How to search the topics with 2 or more seach tags?

Tags: discussion, tag-search

How to search the topics in Stackoverflow by filtering with 2 tags.
For Example , I was able to search the questions with single tag like playframework, but if i want to search with tags like playframework, scala, internalization etc,

Can you please suggest me? It will be helpful to me in learning the concepts from stackoverflow

Comment: No., I didnt understand ..!

Comment: Questions about [so] itself should be asked on [meta].

Answer (score 1):

[tag1][tag2] in searchbar. For example [playframework][scala] and so on...